# Use dnsmasq as DNS for OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, dnsmasq

So to the best of my understanding, I have all the pieces, namely, DNSmasq and OpenVPN working fine, although independently. What I've done?

- Installed OpenVPN using this: https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

  - After install, I'm able to connect client (PC, phone), works. No issue.
- I've installed DNSmasq and also appears to be running and working as expected

  - I've blocked one or two sites i.e pointed them to `0.0.0.0` in the `/etc/hosts` file, and when I do `nslookup thatdomain.com`, I get the `0.0.0.0` response

This is currently my `/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf`

```
local 134.122.60.252
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
duplicate-cn
```

And the only change I've made to the default `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file is uncommenting and indicating the interface this line:

`interface=tun0`

Where I need help?

How to make OpenVPN use DNSmasq for *all* DNS requests. I just can't seem to find a definite answer on how to achieve that, which of the files to change, and what to add.

Am I missing any steps?

Edit:
With the above conf, when I ssh into the openvpn server (the dnsmasq runs also on same server), and I do

`nslookup google.com 10.8.0.1`, it resolve correctly

When I do `nslookup blockthis.com 10.8.0.1` it resolves correct to `0.0.0.0` as expected, as per outlined in the `/etc/hosts` file.

Problem is, when I connect from client to the openvpn, somehow the openvpn isn't handing over the dns resolution to dnsmasq, yet the line `interface=tun0` is enabled in the dnsmasq, and a `netstat -plunt` indicates port 53 is up and running, listened by dnsmasq.

Comment: What are `94.140.14.14` and `94.140.15.15`? If you are running dnsmasq on the same host as the openvpn server, you should probably use `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"` instead. (It does not guarantee that all the clients can / will only use it as the DNS server though, for that you probably need some port-based traffic redirection.)

Comment: The `94.140.14.14` is DNS IP address for AdGuard. Yes, I'm running Dnsmasq on the same host with the OpenVPN server. They both on a single VPS.

Comment: You should configure dnsmasq to use them as its upstream servers.

Comment: @TomYan I think I have already. When I run `sudo service dnsmasq status`, I get one of the lines saying, `using nameserver 94.140.14.14`. Yet when I connect to the VPN, no request works, and DNS resolution doesn't work

Comment: Then update your question, with the current configuration

Comment: @djdomi Updated, only change being from the 94.140.14.14 to 10.8.0.1 in the openvpn server conf

Comment: Since I don't know what kind of clients are used. Please do a `nslookup google.com 10.8.0.1` to verify that the revolver is working. If not, go to the server and do `lsof -i :53` to verify it's listen to all devices. And please remove the incorrect server conf. Show only please the current state.   If you like you can also use `block-outside-dns`

Comment: Not sure if there are specific type of clients, however in my case, it's a phone and laptop, running the openvpn client, connecting to the server using the .ovpn file. `lsof -i :53` shows nothing, but `netstat -plunt` shows port 53 is running listened by dnsmasq. When connected to vpn, `nslookup google.com 10.8.0.1` can't resolve. Same command on server resolves without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it resolved. Needed to open Firewall.

`ufw allow out on tun0`

`ufw allow in on tun0`